# Let C be a cube and let G be its rotational symmetry group. show that G is isomorphic to $S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

Im trying to answer this question using the answer given in

[Let C be a cube and let G be its rotational symmetry group. Outline a proof that G is isomorphic to Sym(4)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795564/let-c-be-a-cube-and-let-g-be-its-rotational-symmetry-group-outline-a-proof-that)

What I did is - I numbered the vertexes and I have the group of long diagonals

$S = {(1,7), (3,5), (4,6) ,(2,8)} $

where 1,2,34 is the button of the cube and 5,6,7,8 is the top (5 above 1)

now i know that all elements of $S_4$ can be made from 2-cycles.

so I need to find a $ g \in G$ that is correspond to every possible 2-cycle in

$S_4$ . I can't find this g. is it one g for every 2-cycle ? or one  for all?

please help me solve that.

also I would like to know how to solve it (also with G operating on the diagonals) with the Orbit-stabilizer theore.

thanks a lot

Comment: I think if you just find $g\in G$ for each two-cycle of $S_4$ (yes, you need a different $g$ for every two-cycle, but a single example shows how to find all of them), then you have shown only that $S_4$ isomorphic to a subgroup of $G$. You would also need a mapping in the other direction (from an appropriate subset of $G$ to $S_4$) to complete the proof.

Comment: that is exactly the problem .. for some reason i can't find a proper explanation of how the symmetric group of a cube looks like. I'm looking for something like i know for $D_4$  . every where I look i see different examples.. can you help with that?  I can also proof that $|G| = 24 $ using the orbit stabiliser, but I'm not sure what rotations can I do . thanks

Comment: The cube has many axes of rotational symmetry, but like any regular polyhedron, there are only three different kinds of them: axis through a face center, axis through the midpoint of an edge, axis through a vertex.

Comment: so i can choose only one of the three to work with? i don't get it

Comment: otherwise i get more than 24

Comment: Hagen von Eitzen just reminded me you can count the elements of $G$ in order to prove that the subgroup isomorphic to $S_4$ is not a _proper_ subgroup, i.e., it must be all of $G$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rotational group of the cube certainly turns a (here always: main) diagonal into a diagonal, hence acts on the set of the four diagonals. This action gives us a homomorphism $\phi\colon G\to \operatorname{Sym}(4)$. On the other hand, $G$ certainly has order $24$: We can pick one of six faces as "ground" face and rotate it in steps of $90^\circ$, thus giving us at least $6\times 4=24$ group elements. Once the ground face is fixed, the whole cube is fixed, thus indeed $|G|=24$. To establish that $\phi$ is an isomorphism it suffices to show that it is one-to-one, or alternatively to show that it is onto.

One quickly verifies that $G$ acts *transitively* on the diagonals (just rotate in steps of $90^\circ$ around the "vertical" axis). In fact the stabilizer of one diagonal still acts transitively on the remaining three diagonals (per rotation by $120^\circ$ around the fixed diagonal, and finally the stabilizer of two diagonals still acts transitively on the remaining two diagonals (rotation by $180^\circ$ around the axis perpendicular to the plane spanned by the two fixed diagonals). We conclude that $\phi[G]$ is all of $\operatorname{Sym}(4)$, as desired.

Comment: i didn't get the fact about the stabiliser and rotating around the fixed diagonal. isn't it enough to say that it is onto Sym(4) by rotating 90 deg around the vertical axis? is there an easier way (more intuitive ) to show that it is onto or one to one without rotating 120 deg? :| thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using the orbit-stabilizer theorem: first of all, we can see that we have "some" homomorphism:

$G \to S_4$ by considering the fact that any such rotation of $G$ permutes the main diagonals.

Now let's consider the action of $G$ on the set of faces of the cube, we have $6$ of these. $G$ clearly always takes a face to a face. Since it is possible, by just using rotations about the center of two opposite faces (which is certainly a subset of $G$) to put any face in any desired position (a six-sided die can be rolled so that "any number is up"), we conclude that $G$ is *transitive* on this set of $6$ faces, that is, the *orbit* of any face under $G$ is the entire set of faces.

Hence if $x$ is any particular face, its orbit $G.x$ has cardinality $6$.

Now the orbit-stabilizer theorem says:

$|G| = |G.x|\ast|\text{Stab}(x)|$.

If a rotation of the cube fixes a face, it must be a rotation about the center of that face (its face is a square, and this is the full rotational symmetry group of a square-reflections of the square don't work, because changing the orientation of any (single) plane in $\Bbb R^3$ changes the orientation of $\Bbb R^3$ itself, and rotations in $\Bbb R^3$ preserve orientation).

So the stabilizer of the face $x$ has order $4$, and thus $|G| = 24$.

Similar arguments can be made by using the set of edges, or the set of vertices, but the elements of the stabilizers are harder to visualize. Basically, the $120^{\circ}$ rotations stabilize a vertex, and the $180^{\circ}$ rotations stabilize an edge, leading to:

$|G| = 8\cdot 3$ or $|G| = 12 \cdot 2$.